# Projectile motion of a charged particle in a homogeneous electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, electric-fields, projectile

I'm reading [an article about projectile motion](http://iopscience.iop.org/0143-0807/14/1/003), but I'm having some trouble with how the author found the equations of motion when a homogeneous electric field is considered.

> To allow an immediate comparison as an example of non-gravitational
> acceleration the corresponding motion of a point charge in a static
> homogeneous electric field is tackled. We choose the charge $q$ and
> the electric field $E$ in the direction of the negative $z$ axis such
> that $qE=mg$ and use the same dimensionless quantities as before (time
> is measured in units of $c/g$ and space in units of $c^2/g$). Also we
> use lower case symbols in the inertial reference frame (t,x,z) to
> facilitate comparison. With:
>
> $t'^2=1+x'^2+z'^2$
>
> the equation of motion $x''=0$,$z'' = -t'$ gives immediately:
>
> $x'=x_0'$, $x=x_0'\tau$ and $z'=z_0'-t$.

All terms are derived with respect to the proper time $\tau$. I don't understand how $qE=mg$ implies $t'^2=1+x'^2+z'^2$ and where $z''=-t'$ comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

1) The first equation is just a rearrangement of the standard expression for the norm of the four-velocity $u=\frac{dx}{d\tau}$ in special relativity: $u_\alpha u^\alpha=1$ (with $c$=1).

2) Since $qE/m=g$, the acceleration in the z-axis $\frac{du^3}{d\tau}$ due to the electric field is obtained from the standard electromagnetic force equation in SR as:

$$ \frac{du^3}{d \tau} = \frac{q}{m} {F^3}_\gamma u^\gamma  = -\frac{q}{m} E u^0 = -g u^0 $$

which is the second equation (with $g=1$).